# How to skip frame in openCV android applitacion?

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, frame, frame-rate

I'm working on android camera application, I want to process my filter on sample frames (not all frames 8-10 fps enough) from camera on my android-openCV application. My frames have Mat format and I am using "SampleJavaCameraView" extends CameraCameraView. Briefly, I want to skip some frame without processing.

Answer (score 1):

Use a counter, and do your processing only if `counter % 10 == 0` (in order to process each tenth frame).